# Jittering cloth when simulating

Tags: modeling, physics

I have this problem where when the cloth plane falls onto the object (A smooth edge square)it jitters a lot similair to how elastic reacts when pulled and released. Im not sure what to do. Any advice?

Comment: please post some screenshots, and at the very least your cloth settings so we have a better understanding of what is happening

Answer (score 1):

So Im sorry it took a while to get back to this question, I solved it by adding a ton of subdivisions which for whatever reason stopped the jittering.